# SSL connection via Domino managed bean to payment gateway fails with 'handshake_failure'

Tags: ssl, lotus-domino, tls1.2, managed-bean, handshake

I have a Java agent that connects to a payment gateway to validate a CC transaction.

Everything seems to work fine when the Java logic is run on my IBM Notes client (9.0.1FP10IF3).

I am now migrating the logic to a managed bean on my Domino server (9.0.1FP6).

Whenever the connection is made through the bean, I observe the following error on the server console...

> HTTP JVM: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:
>   handshake_failure

I am certain it's because the payment gateway with which I am attempting to communicate has recently upgraded to enforce mandatory TLS 1.2 communications.

However, I'm not sure how to enforce those communications on the Domino server side?

I have set the recommended NOTES.INI variables...

DISABLE_SSLV3=1

SSL_DISABLE_TLS_10=1

... and set the 'SSLCipherSpec', but nothing is working.

Here is an excerpt from the logic I'm using to test everything out.

The 'DataOutputStream' line is what triggers the error...

```
URL url = new URL("https://host/endpoint");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", Integer.toString(postContent.length()));
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes(postContent);
out.flush();
out.close();
connection.disconnect();
```

Any advice/assistance would be most appreciated!

Comment: See if this solution works: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21985289

Comment: The notes.ini settings have no impact on the JVM. The article Per Henrik linked should take you in the right direction.

Comment: That was exactly it Per - working perfectly now. Thank s so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Per answered, this document allowed me to resolve the issue straight away...

[www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21985289](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21985289)

Comment: Hi Knut, as the old IBM´s documentation does not exist anymore, is it possible to post the solution here as I need it right now ? Thank you !

Comment: The technote can now be found at HCL: https://hclpnpsupport.hcltech.com/csm?id=kb_article&sys_id=a0e81ca01b2df30083cb86e9cd4bcbe4